# sequalize.js - How to remove double quotes from sequelize generated query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Postgres.
I want to query using sequalize.js with findAll, with the calculated fields I get a strange behavior that i can't eliminate. In practice, on the value of the calculated field, sequalize insert double quotes that block the execution of Postgres query.

SELECT "first", "last", "email", "phone", **"example.string" AS "accessToken"** FROM "utenti" AS "utenti" 
        WHERE "utenti"."email" = 'xxxx' AND "utenti"."password" = 'xxxx');

In bold, there is a problem. If I put single quotes on the calculated field value the query works well
in the connection to the DB I added  **quoteidentifiers: false**,  but now I have the problem of the dot.
if there is a dot inside the value of computed field the double quote is added again !!!!!!!!!!  and query Postgres not work

**This is an example of code node.js **

```
const getTableData = (req, res, db) => {  

  const accessToken='example.string'

  db.utenti.findAll({
    where: {
      [db.Sequelize.Op.and]: 
         [
         {"email":”xxxx”}, 
         {"password":”xxxx”},  
        ]
    } ,
   attributes: [ 'first','last','email','phone', [ accessToken  , "accessToken"]]  
   })  
  .then(items => {
    if(items.length){
      res.json(items)
    } else {    
      res.json({dataExists: 'false'})
    }
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json({dbError: 'db error'}))  

}
```

Help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many tricks with sequalize.js. In the end, I solved it. To manage a calculated field with a constant of type string that contains one o more dot  the correct syntax is this:

**[sequelize.literal ("'" + accessToken + "'"), 'accessToken']**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [sequelize.literal](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal), so your string will not be escaped... as shown below:

```
   attributes: [ 'first','last','email','phone', [ sequelize.literal(accessToken)  , "accessToken"]]
```

Comment: Not Work.Hi Ghassan, surely we have taken a step forward because the double quotes are no longer there but now there are not even single quotes and the Postgres query fails again. I need of single quote at the left and at the right. of the string. this is  the right way-------> 'example.string' AS "accessToken"

Comment: Can you try this sequelize.literal(\`'${accessToken}'`\), I tried it locally, it returns the value of accessToken with single quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can change this :

```
accessToken='example.string'
```

To :

```
accessToken='$example.string$'
```

Comment: Not work.   Return this query                                                                                                                     
 SELECT first, last, email, phone, "$example.string$" AS accessToken  FROM users AS utenti WHERE  "utenti"."email" = 'xxxx' AND "utenti"."password" = 'xxxx'